# Precision on the Baire category theorem

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

More a verification than a question, really.

The Baire category theorem says that in a Baire space a set of the first category has no interior. (Dugundji, Topology, p. 250.)

Does that mean that: ($A$ is of the first category) $\Longleftrightarrow$ ($int A = \emptyset$)?

Comment: No. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $A = \mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}$ under the standard topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It means that$$A\text{ is of first category}\color{red}{\implies}\mathring A=\emptyset.$$It is *not* an equivalence. For instance, the interior of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is empty (in $\mathbb R$), but $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is *not* of first category.